# В google sheets не могу применить Ctrl+C Ctrl+V. Не работает копипаст ячеек

Tags: google-chrome, таблицы, google-spreadsheet

Почистил кеш, куки, реестр.
Прогнал Хром на вирусы.
Методом проб увидел, что не хочет копировать/вставлять **только** в Хроме. Настройки в браузере и Гугл диске не менял.
В Гугл документах всё работает. Такое впечатление, что стоит запрет на копирование и вставку но защиты на ячейках нет.
Поиск не дал результатов. Может кто сталкивался - хелпните.

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5356516?hl=en

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica
По ссылке:
Recommended Answer:
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

После перезагрузки ноутбука заработало. Почему и что было причиной - не понятно.
Ноут Asus N75s. OC Win 10 x64.

Comment: Перед переазгрузкой можно было бы: 1) закрыть все окна Хрома; 2) убить все процессы Хрома; 3) логоф/логон в ОС.